# Enviar pedido de pareamento

Tags: android

Eu estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo android para conexão bluetooth, atualmente meu aplicativo esta listando os dispositivos pareados e busca novos dispositivos.

Eu preciso nesse momento de um exemplo de código que pega o endereço `1b:2f:5d:6a:7a` e envia uma solicitação de pareamento.

```
private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;

    public AcceptThread() {
        // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmServerSocket,
        // because mmServerSocket is final
        BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
        try {
            // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the client code
            tmp = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME, MY_UUID);
        } catch (IOException e) { }
        mmServerSocket = tmp;
    }

    public void run() {
        BluetoothSocket socket = null;
        // Keep listening until exception occurs or a socket is returned
        while (true) {
            try {
                socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                break;
            }
            // If a connection was accepted
            if (socket != null) {
                // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
                manageConnectedSocket(socket);
                mmServerSocket.close();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /** Will cancel the listening socket, and cause the thread to finish */
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmServerSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) { }
    }
}
```

Comment: OLá @gilliard-santos você já tentou alguma coisa? caso sim seria interessante colocar sua tentativa para que possamos analisar e corrigir/melhorar seu código.

Comment: Eu adicionei a minha pergunta o código que eu tenho, mas eu não sei se é para solicitar pareamento e não sei onde eu insiro o endereço do dispositivo que desejo me conectar.

Answer (score 2):

Tenho esse código aqui, que uso em minhas aplicações. Ele deve dar uma luz sobre como conectar.

Esse código utiliza um tratamento `try-catch`, que alguns podem não gostar, mas é para poder tratar o caso do dispositivo ainda sendo pareado.

```
private static final UUID SERIAL_PORT_SERVICE_CLASS_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");
private BluetoothDevice mDevice;
private BluetoothSocket mSocket;
private BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;

private void createConnection() throws IOException {
    try {
        if (mAdapter == null)
            mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        mDevice = mAdapter.getRemoteDevice("MAC ADDRESS DESEJADO");
        if (mDevice == null)
            throw new IOException();

        //Ou pode utilizar outro UUID, dependendo da necessidade
        mSocket = mDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(SERIAL_PORT_SERVICE_CLASS_UUID);
        try {
            mSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if ( < AINDA ESTAVA PAREANDO > ) {
                //É possível descobrir se o dispositivo já estava
                //pareado antes da chamada createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(),
                //e tratar de uma forma diferente aqui, pedindo para o usuário
                //aguardar, ou outra mensagem que não seja de erro fatal

                //Para isso, basta verificar se o dispositivo estava ou não no Set
                //retornado por mAdapter.getBondedDevices()
                return;
            }

            try {
                //Caso contrário, tenta outro método para criar o socket
                //(para funcionar no HTC desire) - crédito de Michael Biermann
                Method method = mDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket",
                                                             new Class[] { int.class});
                mSocket = (BluetoothSocket)method.invoke(mDevice, Integer.valueOf(1));
                mSocket.connect();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                //O reflection falhou, aborta por aqui
                throw new IOException(e);
            }
        }

        //A partir daqui é OK chamar mSocket.getIntputStream() e
        //mSocket.getOutputStream()

    } catch (IOException e) {
        //Ver comentários sobre pareamento acima (o tratamento deve ser repetido aqui)
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Gostei do código, mas esse código solicita o pareamento ?

Comment: Serve para especificar qual serviço você deseja acessar do outro dispositivo, por exemplo, no caso do exemplo é para se conectar utilizando o protocolo de porta serial Bluetooth. Mas poderia ser outro serviço, como fone de ouvido, teclado, etc...

Comment: Entendi, mas esse código solicita o pareamento ao outro dispositivo ?

Comment: Nos aparelhos que eu testei, sempre que se inicia uma conexão com um dispositivo não pareado, o Android iniciou automaticamente o processo de pareamento. Por isso do tratamento especial no código para ver se o dispositivo ainda estava pareando, e nesses caso, mostrar uma mensagem não de erro, mas algo como "Dispositivo ainda pareando, tente novamente depois..."

Comment: Legal, tenho só mais uma dúvida, gostaria que após buscar por novos dispositivos não pareados, somente seja exibidos na lista os aparelhos da marca Samsung, como posso fazer ?

Comment: Isso pode ser feito comparando os três primeiros bytes do MAC do dispositivo, que corresponde à companhia (vendor). Eu encontrei esse site aqui, que pode te dar uma ajuda: http://www.coffer.com/mac_find/?string=samsung

Comment: Teria algum exemplo que compara o código MAC ?

Comment: Dado que você tenha uma string com o MAC, na forma `"XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX"`, você pode fazer `MAC.toLowerCase(Locale.US).startsWith("0a:00:12")`, supondo que você queira saber se o MAC inicia por `"0a:00:12"` (Lembre-se de escrever com letras minúsculas, por causa do `toLowerCase()`)

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Sem problemas! Se tudo der certo, só não se esqueça de marcar a pergunta como respondida :)